# Get Values of OHLC of specific timeframe candle - using pinescript

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to get O,H,L,C values of first 15m candle of the session.

**For eg:** session timings is `0930-1600`, I need to get values of `0930-0945` candle.

Current timeframe of the chart can be either in 15m interval or in any interval(Minutes/Hourly/Daily/...), With this condition I need to get values of each O,H,L,C using Pinescript

Comment: The hardest part of this is getting the correct time interval based on the timeframe of the chart, so for example, if it's a 5 minute timeframe, it would be every three candles, a 1 minute timeframe would be every 15 candles, a 15 minute timeframe would be every candle. Anything after a 15 minute timeframe and you'll have to check the time since open. If it's a 30 minute timeframe, if it's 15 minutes since open, get olhc, etc. `minuteDifference = (time - time[50]) / 60000` where time[50] is your opening bar. When minuteDifference == 15, get the olhc.